# How to fix 'MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out' error in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose, ubuntu-20.04

I need to connect mongodb (which is running inside docker container in ubuntu vps) to my node application. when I deploy it on server, it get following error. Is there any way to fix it?

```
 MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out
     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri 
     (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:797:32)
     at Mongoose.createConnection (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:276:10)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/config/database.js:19:6)
     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require 
        (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the- 
         middle/index.js:80:39)     
     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18) {
     reason: TopologyDescription {
     type: 'Unknown',
     servers: Map(1) { '147.60.221.79:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
     stale: false,
     compatible: true,
     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
     localThresholdMS: 15,
     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
   }
 }
```

PS: I don't have any idea of this error.

Comment: Have you found a solution now?

Comment: No. I have not found any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in package.json you add latest mongoose.

I read in another post with a lot of information that the problem is that latest mongoose cannot handle well local conections, and the solution that help me as well get down mongoose version into 5.8.13.

Post that helped me: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9308